# execute macro with arguments within batch file using imacros extension and firefox

Tags: batch-file, arguments, imacros

I'm working on a batch script that calls macros using code like the following :

"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" imacros://run/?m=current2.iim

I'm using firefox imacros extension not the executable (not free).

Is it possible to pass value to the macros within the batch ?
When you use imacros.exe, it is possible by adding -var_Varname value.

Is there an way to do the same only with firefox extension?

Thanks a lot for your help.
Cheers.

Comment: According to the Command Line reference, -var_Varname is only for imacros.exe. I don't see any way to do the same thing with the browser extension, though there is a little bit of something that might help here: http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Firefox#Command_Line_Support

Comment: Moreover there can be a workaround to pass some values by means of the clipboard or text files.

Comment: Thank you both guys ! I've solved my problem coping values to clipboard from the batch script then get it inside the macro using build in variable !CLIPBOARD. Thanks !!!